# How do I turn this function to a generic type?

Tags: swift, generics

How would I go about turning this function into a generic type?

```
func addThreeValue(value1:String,value2:String,value3:String) -> String {
    let concatenated = value1 + value2 + value3

    return concatenated
}
```

Comment: Why do you want to? What is your goal?

Comment: Because I have two different function doing the same thing. One is adding strings together and the other integers. Plus I want to learn how to do it. Thanks

Comment: There isn't a built-in protocol which supports the + function for both String and Int. You'd have to define your own.

Comment: Can you show me an example of what you just explained. I am new to the language and it's my first time dealing with generics. Thank you for the help!

Comment: Or how would I just create a generic function to do either one separately?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will **not** work:

```
func addThreeValues<T>(v1: T, _ v2: T, _ v3: T) -> T {
    return v1 + v2 + v3
}
```

Because the compiler doesn't know about any `+` operator which works with `T`s.

You need to *constrain* the generic parameter so that it can find a suitable `+` operator. The [IntegerType protocol](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Reference/Swift_IntegerType_Protocol/index.html) provides one:

```
func addThreeValues<T: IntegerType>(v1: T, _ v2: T, _ v3: T) -> T {
    return v1 + v2 + v3
}
```

However, String doesn't conform to the IntegerType protocol:

```
addThreeValues("a", "b", "c")  // error: cannot invoke 'addThreeValues' with an argument list of type '(String, String, String)'
```

To work around this you could define your own protocol and provide conformances for whichever types you want to use:

```
protocol Addable {
    func +(lhs: Self, rhs: Self) -> Self
}
extension String: Addable {}
extension Int: Addable {}

func addThreeValues<T: Addable>(v1: T, _ v2: T, _ v3: T) -> T {
    return v1 + v2 + v3
}
```

Now this works:

```
addThreeValues(1, 2, 3)        // returns 6
addThreeValues("a", "b", "c")  // returns "abc"
```

Comment: Thanks for the great explanation! I accepted this answer.